# Horizontal line not showing in matplotlib since it coincides with bottom spine

Tags: python, matplotlib

Good day, I have encountered a problem with plotting lines with matplotlib. Consider the following example:

```
x = [1]*5
y = [3]*5

plt.plot(x, 'r')
plt.plot(y, 'orange')

plt.show()
```

This shows an "empty plot" since the horizontal lines overlap with the top and bottom spines. Trying to remove these spines with the following lines:

```
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```

the result is that only the line on top is visible. Is there any way to view the bottom line also without changing the ylim?

Comment: Executing the code I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMxGy.png). It is not an "empty plot". Mpl automatically adjusts the ylim.

Comment: can you go into detail about the exact purpose of this? What is the final plot supposed to look like?

Comment: Weird. Your mpl looks dope. Mine looks bad [like this](http://i64.tinypic.com/nwg4r6.png) and [this with the tick visibility off](http://i66.tinypic.com/29cwgn.png). I'm in Win7 Python 3.4 if that helps.

Comment: I have a series of plots with a horizontal line coincides with the bottom spine. Unfortunately, I have a constraint that unables me to adjust the ylim.

Comment: Links to images are not working. Would it be enough to just make the line a bit thicker to let it stick out, e.g. `plt.plot(x, 'r', linewidth=3)`

Comment: Sorry, Imgur is blocked in the school. tried tinypic and but it looks like the linked are scammed. Trying again: plots look [like this](https://s28.postimg.org/d0sa4idtp/mpl1.png) and [this with the tick visibility off](https://s28.postimg.org/etv6stz0d/mpl2.png).

Comment: What limitation is this that prevents you from changing the ylim? Could you just add some margin, e.g. `plt.margins(y=0.001)`?

Comment: Thicker linewidth solves the problem, but I wouldn't want to go in that direction because I'll only know if that horizontal line is the bottom after plotting all the lines and a replot might be needed. It also looks ugly af when the plot are panned. Thanks tho!

Comment: I need to replicate a graph from MATLAB. Adding a margin solves the problem, y=0.01. Thanks, kind sir!

Edit: oops, margin also changes ylim. :(

Comment: Third alternative: set a higher zorder for the lines: `plt.plot(x, 'r', zorder=10)`